# Error in build plan when converting to Maven project

Tags: java, selenium, maven, exception

I am using Eclipse , created a new Java project and when converting to Maven project, I am getting Core Exception:could not calculate build plan: plug in org.Apache. maven.plug-ins:maven compiler plug-in:3.8.1 or one of dependencies could not be resolved.
I tried maven clean, maven install and maven compile and no luck.

Comment: Check first on plain command line ... and if errors occur please post them here..

Comment: Hi, I don’t have maven installed on my system, it is from the Eclipse marketplace

Comment: First install Maven on your system and run your build from plain command line... Download: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi Installation: https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: I did install and searched from the command prompt, it says that the command is unrecognized.

Comment: Than your installation is broken or not done correctly ... have you follow the guide for installation?